# The bar in jScrollPane dissapears when jTextArea gets too big

Tags: jscrollpane, jtextarea

When entering to many lines of text into a jTextArea, at some point the bar dissapears to scroll down.
(Even without that bar, I'm able to scroll up/down but it looks nasty without it)

This is how it looks with the bar (on the right side).
[image]

And some lines later, after the bar got really small because of more lines, it dissapears at some point when adding more lines.
[image]

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution which I found was changing your [Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)
Standard should look like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {

                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });


}
```

By changing Nimbus to one of the other themes you will also change the Slider.

Comment: Okay, wasn't exactly what i was looking for, but this did the trick. Also good to know you can change layouts